# How to get all the DATES between two input DATES In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

The user inputs the starting date and the end date. I want to get the dates between these two input dates.

I tried this:

```
(datestart..dateend).to_a
```

but it returns the whole month, and when I choose from the previous year, it gives an error `ArgumentError (invalid date):`.

This is the example return when I choose Jan. 1 2017 and Jan. 2 2017 - the result was whole month and an inaccurate dates.

```
[Tue, 12 Jan 2016, Wed, 13 Jan 2016, Thu, 14 Jan 2016, Fri, 15 Jan 2016, Sat, 16 Jan 2016, Sun, 17 Jan 2016, Mon, 18 Jan 2016, Tue, 19 Jan 2016, Wed, 20 Jan 2016, Thu, 21 Jan 2016, Fri, 22 Jan 2016, Sat, 23 Jan 2016, Sun, 24 Jan 2016, Mon, 25 Jan 2016, Tue, 26 Jan 2016, Wed, 27 Jan 2016, Thu, 28 Jan 2016, Fri, 29 Jan 2016, Sat, 30 Jan 2016, Sun, 31 Jan 2016, Mon, 01 Feb 2016, Tue, 02 Feb 2016, Wed, 03 Feb 2016, Thu, 04 Feb 2016, Fri, 05 Feb 2016, Sat, 06 Feb 2016, Sun, 07 Feb 2016, Mon, 08 Feb 2016, Tue, 09 Feb 2016, Wed, 10 Feb 2016, Thu, 11 Feb 2016, Fri, 12 Feb 2016]
```

Update! I Fix it by using

```
Date.strptime(params[:datestart_stat], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Are you using this dates to make database query ?

Comment: no Im not using dates to query from database.

Comment: Is the input a string? What format? The question is not clear.

Comment: the inputed was date. to make sure I get date I use parse.. this was my code. (Date.parse(params[:datestart_stat])..Date.parse(params[:dateend_stat])).to_a

Comment: please add the expected output

Comment: Are you inputting dates thus: 1st Jan = "1/1/2016", 2nd Jan = "1/2/2016" or is 2nd Jan "2/1/2016"? This may be a region issue. The first is valid in the UK, and the second is valid in US.

Answer (score 10):

```
start_date = Date.parse('date start')
end_date = Date.parse('date end')
(start..endd).to_a
```

Comment: currently Im using that code. my code was this (Date.parse(params[:datestart_stat])..Date.parse(params[:dateend_stat])).to_a but it returns a whole dates of the month. :( p.s. thankyou for the comment

Comment: Then whats the issue ?

Comment: I want only the dates between the dates I inputed not the whole month. like for example january 1 and january 5. then it should return janaury 1,2,3,4, and janauray 5.

Comment: The above code doing the same. Please share what the values you are getting as inputs values into console.

Comment: I tried it in the console and the result was right. maybe I have a problem in the inputed dates. thankyou for your help. I will try much harder to find my error. thankyou very much @Bharat soni

Comment: Thankyou @Bharat I was able to get an accurate result now. the problem was my parsing. I change Date.parse to Date.strptime and now it work like charm. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Update! I was able to fix my mistake now. I just change the

```
Date.parse(params[:datestart_stat])
# to 
Date.strptime(params[:datestart_stat], '%m/%d/%Y')
```

thank you guys.